# Javascript - Value of Text Input Field Disappears Upon Manual Input on Different Text Input Field

Tags: javascript, reactjs

And thank you kindly for clicking my post! I am an admittedly very novice coder, learning only things to make my non-programming job's workflow more convenient. I am trying to create a script to automate consultation appointments in our firm's case management website. I was able to make an Autohotkey script based on pixel recognition work for this purpose, but it was not transferable to coworkers due to screen resolution differences. I made it with Python and Selenium webdrivers, but that was too slow. So, alas, I decided to learn Javascript. And I hit a roadblock which, for the first time, I need to ask a community for help on.

My code is just simply changing the value of a text input field:

```
document.querySelector("#first_name").value = "Jane"
```

I have tested this code on both the problematic case management website and a generic Gmail account creation page.

When making a Gmail account, the code works perfectly.

[Successful Code Execution on Gmail Account Creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oakkg.png)

As you can see, I set the value of the first name field to "Jane" with Javascript and I was able to manually type "Doe" in the last name field. I was able to create a Gmail account by manually completing the password fields and never needed to focus the first name input field, manually or otherwise.

This does not work on the case management website. I can set the value of the first name input field to "Jane," but manually clicking on the last name field and typing anything will immediately result in the value of the first name input field disappearing. "Jane" will disappear, leaving only the "First Name" faded placeholder text, the very moment I type the first letter in the last name input field.

[Value Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y12vg.png)

[Aaaand it's gone.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMSQl.png)

As I was trying to solve this by myself for the last time before posting, I discovered, for the first time, that the value I was setting through Javascript was "real" so to speak. I apologize for my lack of knowledge on how to technically explain the behavior I discovered. I realized that after I set the value of the first name input field to "Jane," I can manually click the first name input field and manually type text after "Jane." When I manually click on the last name input field and manually type text, "Jane" actually doesn't disappear anymore!!! I was so surprised that I just typed "Wtf" for the last name. Sure enough, JaneDoe Wtf was submitted successfully as a client to our website as a contact. So that threw out all my attempted solutions with event.preventDefault() and related lines of thinking that I was supposed to handle an event or figure out an issue with form submissions lol.

[JaneDoe Wtf Was Born](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqwPV.png)

I suspect that the input fields that I am working with is a jQuery object since the "Add Contact" form pops up after the blue "Add Contact" button is clicked. However, my attempts to research and try various solutions with jQuery and DOM have been unsuccessful.

[Here is a screenshot of the relevant website code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxF2m.png)  A code snippet of the relevant div is below. Notably, this code does not exist in the website page's source code, which I suspect is the root of my problem.

```html
<div class="ReactModalPortal"><div class="ReactModal__Overlay ReactModal__Overlay--after-open react-modal-overlay"><div class="ReactModal__Content ReactModal__Content--after-open react-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-label="Modal"><div class="react-modal-content popup new-client-modal react-draggable" style="touch-action: none; width: 800px; visibility: initial; transform: translate(0px, 0px);"><div class="modal-header"><div class="header-left-group"><h1 class="mb-0 h5"><span class="modal-title">Add Contact</span></h1></div><div class="header-right-group"><button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button></div></div><div class="modal-body"><form><div class="bootstrap form-component"><div><div class="form-group row"><label for="first_name" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Name</label><div class="col"><div class=""><div class="row no-gutters"><div class="col-5 pr-2"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="First Name" autocomplete="off" data-testid="first_name" value=""></div></div></div></div><div class="col-2"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="middle_initial" name="middle_initial" class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="M" autocomplete="off" data-testid="middle_initial" value=""></div></div></div></div><div class="col-5 pl-2"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Last Name" autocomplete="off" data-testid="last_name" value=""></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="email" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Email</label><div class="col"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="email" name="email" class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="example@email.com" autocomplete="off" data-testid="email" value=""></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="contact_group" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Contact Group</label><div class="col"><div class=""><div class="row "><div class="col-4 test-contact-group"><div><div class=""><select id="contact_group" name="contact_group" class="form-control custom-select col "><option value="759487">Client</option><option value="759490">Co-counsel</option><option value="759488">Expert</option><option value="759489">Judge</option><option value="842855">Notary</option><option value="874268">Opposing Party</option><option value="759491">Unassigned</option></select></div></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Add new contact group</button></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="login_enabled" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Enable Client Portal</label><div class="col"><div class="test-enable-client-portal-switch"><div class="d-inline-flex align-items-center"><div class="switch switch--checked"><div class="switch-track"><div class="switch-track-check"><svg width="14" height="11" viewBox="0 0 14 11" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>switch-check</title><path d="M11.264 0L5.26 6.004 2.103 2.847 0 4.95l5.26 5.26 8.108-8.107L11.264 0" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></div><div class="switch-track-x"><svg width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 10 10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><title>switch-x</title><path d="M9.9 2.12L7.78 0 4.95 2.828 2.12 0 0 2.12l2.83 2.83L0 7.776 2.123 9.9 4.95 7.07 7.78 9.9 9.9 7.776 7.072 4.95 9.9 2.12" fill="#fff" fill-rule="evenodd"></path></svg></div></div><div class="switch-thumb"></div><input class="switch-screenreader-only" type="checkbox" data-testid="switch-field" id="login_enabled" name="login_enabled"></div><label for="login_enabled" class="ml-2 mb-0"></label></div><div><div><div>Securely share documents, invoices, and messages with your client. They will receive a welcome email with login instructions. Your client will only have access to items that you explicitly share.</div><a href="https://help.mycase.com/s/article/What-will-my-client-see-when-I-invite-them-to-the-portal" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">What will my clients see?</a></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="cell_phone" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Cell phone</label><div class="col"><div><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="cell_phone" name="cell_phone" class="form-control " type="tel" placeholder="(xxx)-xxx-xxxx" data-testid="cell_phone" value=""></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="work_phone" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Work phone</label><div class="col"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="work_phone" name="work_phone" class="form-control col-6" type="text" placeholder="Work" autocomplete="off" data-testid="work_phone" value=""></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="home_phone" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Home phone</label><div class="col"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="home_phone" name="home_phone" class="form-control col-6" type="text" placeholder="Home" autocomplete="off" data-testid="home_phone" value=""></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="address1" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address</label><div class="col"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="address1" name="address1" class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Address" autocomplete="off" data-testid="address1" value=""></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="address2" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Address 2</label><div class="col"><div><div class=""><div class="input-group"><input id="address2" name="address2" class="form-control " type="text" placeholder="Address 2" autocomplete="off" data-testid="address2" value=""></div></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="city_state_zipcode_city" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">City, State, Zip Code</label><div class="col"><div class="row "><div class="pr-2 col-6"><input id="city_state_zipcode_city" name="city_state_zipcode_city" placeholder="City" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control form-control" value=""></div><div class="p-0 col-2"><select id="city_state_zipcode_state" name="city_state_zipcode_state" class="custom-select form-control form-control"><option value=""></option><option title="Alaska" value="AK">AK</option><option title="Alabama" value="AL">AL</option><option title="Arkansas" value="AR">AR</option><option title="Arizona" value="AZ">AZ</option><option title="California" value="CA">CA</option><option title="Colorado" value="CO">CO</option><option title="Connecticut" value="CT">CT</option><option title="Washington, D.C." value="DC">DC</option><option title="Delaware" value="DE">DE</option><option title="Florida" value="FL">FL</option><option title="Georgia" value="GA">GA</option><option title="Hawaii" value="HI">HI</option><option title="Iowa" value="IA">IA</option><option title="Idaho" value="ID">ID</option><option title="Illinois" value="IL">IL</option><option title="Indiana" value="IN">IN</option><option title="Kansas" value="KS">KS</option><option title="Kentucky" value="KY">KY</option><option title="Louisiana" value="LA">LA</option><option title="Massachusetts" value="MA">MA</option><option title="Maryland" value="MD">MD</option><option title="Maine" value="ME">ME</option><option title="Michigan" value="MI">MI</option><option title="Minnesota" value="MN">MN</option><option title="Missouri" value="MO">MO</option><option title="Mississippi" value="MS">MS</option><option title="Montana" value="MT">MT</option><option title="North Carolina" value="NC">NC</option><option title="North Dakota" value="ND">ND</option><option title="Nebraska" value="NE">NE</option><option title="New Hampshire" value="NH">NH</option><option title="New Jersey" value="NJ">NJ</option><option title="New Mexico" value="NM">NM</option><option title="Nevada" value="NV">NV</option><option title="New York" value="NY">NY</option><option title="Ohio" value="OH">OH</option><option title="Oklahoma" value="OK">OK</option><option title="Oregon" value="OR">OR</option><option title="Pennsylvania" value="PA">PA</option><option title="Rhode Island" value="RI">RI</option><option title="South Carolina" value="SC">SC</option><option title="South Dakota" value="SD">SD</option><option title="Tennessee" value="TN">TN</option><option title="Texas" value="TX">TX</option><option title="Utah" value="UT">UT</option><option title="Virginia" value="VA">VA</option><option title="Vermont" value="VT">VT</option><option title="Washington" value="WA">WA</option><option title="Wisconsin" value="WI">WI</option><option title="West Virginia" value="WV">WV</option><option title="Wyoming" value="WY">WY</option><option title="U.S. Armed Forces Americas" value="AA">AA</option><option title="U.S. Armed Forces Europe" value="AE">AE</option><option title="U.S. Armed Forces Pacific" value="AP">AP</option><option title="American Samoa" value="AS">AS</option><option title="Micronesia" value="FM">FM</option><option title="Guam" value="GU">GU</option><option title="Marshall Islands" value="MH">MH</option><option title="Northern Mariana Islands" value="MP">MP</option><option title="Puerto Rico" value="PR">PR</option><option title="Virgin Islands" value="VI">VI</option></select></div><div class="pl-2 col-4"><input id="city_state_zipcode_zipcode" name="city_state_zipcode_zipcode" placeholder="Zip Code" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control form-control" value=""></div></div></div></div><div class="form-group row"><label for="country" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Country</label><div class="col"><select id="country" name="country" class="custom-select form-control"><option value=""></option><option value="US">United States</option><option value="CA">Canada</option><option value="AF">Afghanistan</option><option value="AX">Åland Islands</option><option value="AL">Albania</option><option value="DZ">Algeria</option><option value="AD">Andorra</option><option value="AO">Angola</option><option value="AI">Anguilla</option><option value="AG">Antigua &amp; Barbuda</option><option value="AR">Argentina</option><option value="AM">Armenia</option><option value="AQ">Antarctica</option><option value="AS">American Samoa</option><option value="AW">Aruba</option><option value="AU">Australia</option><option value="AT">Austria</option><option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option><option value="BS">Bahamas</option><option value="BH">Bahrain</option><option value="BD">Bangladesh</option><option value="BB">Barbados</option><option value="BY">Belarus</option><option value="BE">Belgium</option><option value="BZ">Belize</option><option value="BJ">Benin</option><option value="BM">Bermuda</option><option value="BT">Bhutan</option><option value="BO">Bolivia</option><option value="BA">Bosnia &amp; Herzegovina</option><option value="BW">Botswana</option><option value="BV">Bouvet Island</option><option value="BR">Brazil</option><option value="IO">British Indian Ocean Territory</option><option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option><option value="BN">Brunei</option><option value="BG">Bulgaria</option><option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option><option value="BI">Burundi</option><option value="KH">Cambodia</option><option value="CM">Cameroon</option><option value="CV">Cape Verde</option><option value="BQ">Caribbean Netherlands</option><option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option><option value="CF">Central African Republic</option><option value="TD">Chad</option><option value="CL">Chile</option><option value="CN">China</option><option value="CX">Christmas Island</option><option value="CC">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option><option value="CO">Colombia</option><option value="KM">Comoros</option><option value="CG">Congo - Brazzaville</option><option value="CD">Congo - Kinshasa</option><option value="CK">Cook Islands</option><option value="CR">Costa Rica</option><option value="HR">Croatia</option><option value="CU">Cuba</option><option value="CW">Curaçao</option><option value="CY">Cyprus</option><option value="CZ">Czechia</option><option value="CI">Côte d’Ivoire</option><option value="DK">Denmark</option><option value="DJ">Djibouti</option><option value="DM">Dominica</option><option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option><option value="EC">Ecuador</option><option value="EG">Egypt</option><option value="SV">El Salvador</option><option value="GQ">Equatorial Guinea</option><option value="ER">Eritrea</option><option value="EE">Estonia</option><option value="ET">Ethiopia</option><option value="FK">Falkland Islands</option><option value="FO">Faroe Islands</option><option value="FJ">Fiji</option><option value="FI">Finland</option><option value="FR">France</option><option value="GF">French Guiana</option><option value="PF">French Polynesia</option><option value="TF">French Southern Territories</option><option value="GA">Gabon</option><option value="GM">Gambia</option><option value="GE">Georgia</option><option value="DE">Germany</option><option value="GH">Ghana</option><option value="GI">Gibraltar</option><option value="GR">Greece</option><option value="GL">Greenland</option><option value="GD">Grenada</option><option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option><option value="GU">Guam</option><option value="GT">Guatemala</option><option value="GG">Guernsey</option><option value="GN">Guinea</option><option value="GW">Guinea-Bissau</option><option value="GY">Guyana</option><option value="HT">Haiti</option><option value="HM">Heard &amp; McDonald Islands</option><option value="HN">Honduras</option><option value="HK">Hong Kong SAR China</option><option value="HU">Hungary</option><option value="IS">Iceland</option><option value="IN">India</option><option value="ID">Indonesia</option><option value="IR">Iran</option><option value="IQ">Iraq</option><option value="IE">Ireland</option><option value="IM">Isle of Man</option><option value="IL">Israel</option><option value="IT">Italy</option><option value="JM">Jamaica</option><option value="JP">Japan</option><option value="JE">Jersey</option><option value="JO">Jordan</option><option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option><option value="KE">Kenya</option><option value="KI">Kiribati</option><option value="XK">Kosovo</option><option value="KW">Kuwait</option><option value="KG">Kyrgyzstan</option><option value="LA">Laos</option><option value="LV">Latvia</option><option value="LB">Lebanon</option><option value="LS">Lesotho</option><option value="LR">Liberia</option><option value="LY">Libya</option><option value="LI">Liechtenstein</option><option value="LT">Lithuania</option><option value="LU">Luxembourg</option><option value="MO">Macau SAR China</option><option value="MK">Macedonia</option><option value="MG">Madagascar</option><option value="MW">Malawi</option><option value="MY">Malaysia</option><option value="MV">Maldives</option><option value="ML">Mali</option><option value="MT">Malta</option><option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option><option value="MQ">Martinique</option><option value="MR">Mauritania</option><option value="MU">Mauritius</option><option value="YT">Mayotte</option><option value="MX">Mexico</option><option value="FM">Micronesia</option><option value="MD">Moldova</option><option value="MC">Monaco</option><option value="MN">Mongolia</option><option value="ME">Montenegro</option><option value="MS">Montserrat</option><option value="MA">Morocco</option><option value="MZ">Mozambique</option><option value="MM">Myanmar (Burma)</option><option value="NA">Namibia</option><option value="NR">Nauru</option><option value="NP">Nepal</option><option value="NL">Netherlands</option><option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option><option value="NC">New Caledonia</option><option value="NZ">New Zealand</option><option value="NI">Nicaragua</option><option value="NE">Niger</option><option value="NG">Nigeria</option><option value="NU">Niue</option><option value="NF">Norfolk Island</option><option value="KP">North Korea</option><option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="NO">Norway</option><option value="OM">Oman</option><option value="PK">Pakistan</option><option value="PW">Palau</option><option value="PS">Palestinian Territories</option><option value="PA">Panama</option><option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option><option value="PY">Paraguay</option><option value="PE">Peru</option><option value="PH">Philippines</option><option value="PN">Pitcairn Islands</option><option value="PL">Poland</option><option value="PT">Portugal</option><option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option><option value="QA">Qatar</option><option value="RE">Réunion</option><option value="RO">Romania</option><option value="RU">Russia</option><option value="RW">Rwanda</option><option value="WS">Samoa</option><option value="SM">San Marino</option><option value="ST">São Tomé &amp; Príncipe</option><option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option><option value="SN">Senegal</option><option value="RS">Serbia</option><option value="SC">Seychelles</option><option value="SL">Sierra Leone</option><option value="SG">Singapore</option><option value="SX">Sint Maarten</option><option value="SK">Slovakia</option><option value="SI">Slovenia</option><option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option><option value="SO">Somalia</option><option value="ZA">South Africa</option><option value="GS">South Georgia &amp; South Sandwich Islands</option><option value="KR">South Korea</option><option value="SS">South Sudan</option><option value="ES">Spain</option><option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option><option value="BL">St. Barthélemy</option><option value="SH">St. Helena</option><option value="KN">St. Kitts &amp; Nevis</option><option value="LC">St. Lucia</option><option value="MF">St. Martin</option><option value="PM">St. Pierre &amp; Miquelon</option><option value="VC">St. Vincent &amp; Grenadines</option><option value="SD">Sudan</option><option value="SR">Suriname</option><option value="SJ">Svalbard &amp; Jan Mayen</option><option value="SZ">Swaziland</option><option value="SE">Sweden</option><option value="CH">Switzerland</option><option value="SY">Syria</option><option value="TW">Taiwan</option><option value="TJ">Tajikistan</option><option value="TZ">Tanzania</option><option value="TH">Thailand</option><option value="TL">Timor-Leste</option><option value="TG">Togo</option><option value="TK">Tokelau</option><option value="TO">Tonga</option><option value="TT">Trinidad &amp; Tobago</option><option value="TN">Tunisia</option><option value="TR">Turkey</option><option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option><option value="TC">Turks &amp; Caicos Islands</option><option value="TV">Tuvalu</option><option value="UM">U.S. Outlying Islands</option><option value="UG">Uganda</option><option value="UA">Ukraine</option><option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option><option value="GB">United Kingdom</option><option value="UY">Uruguay</option><option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option><option value="VU">Vanuatu</option><option value="VA">Vatican City</option><option value="VE">Venezuela</option><option value="VN">Vietnam</option><option value="VI">U.S. Virgin Islands</option><option value="WF">Wallis &amp; Futuna</option><option value="EH">Western Sahara</option><option value="YE">Yemen</option><option value="ZM">Zambia</option><option value="ZW">Zimbabwe</option></select></div></div><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-link p-0 border-0 form-group">Add More Information <i class="fas fa-sort-down align-text-top"></i></button></div><div><button type="button" class="btn btn-link p-0 border-0 form-group">Custom Fields <i class="fas fa-sort-down align-text-top"></i></button></div></div></div><div class="justify-content-between modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</button><div><button type="submit" class="mr-1 btn btn-secondary">Save &amp; Add Case</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-cta-primary">Save Contact</button></div></div></form></div></div></div></div></div>
```

I am truly grateful for any help and please feel free to let me know if I should provide any further information.

Update. I figured out how to copy the HTML DOM tree and CSS of the webpage I am having the issue with and copied the whole HTML DOM tree and CSS and pasted them in the code snippet tool, then ran it. Stack Overflow's code snippet tool reproduced the webpage with the Add Contact form just fine. But I changed the value of the first name input text field with the same Javascript method and... I can manually type in the last name input text field just fine. The problem I have on the real webpage doesn't occur in the simulated webpage, even with the exact same HTML DOM tree and CSS. I can't post the whole HTML and CSS due to the 30,000 character limit, but I'm so confused. Any tips on what else I should be looking at? I don't know if the real webpage has any Javascript of its own that is wiping my values upon manual input, but not sure how to check to make sure. @-@

[image: Copy Paste of Full HTML DOM Tree in Stack Overflow Code Snippet Does Not Reproduce Problem]

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: I read the documentation prior to posting, but I was unable to initially figure out how to copy-paste the HTML DOM tree I took a picture of. I typed it out and provided it as a code snippet to this post. Please let me know if I should provide anything else. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

it's likely the management site using a shadow DOM. That's the case if it uses React or Angular as a front end. The values of all the input elements are stored in the shadow DOM (javascript) and changes made to the live DOM get overwritten whenever the page rerenders. These frameworks will monitor the events on the elements and save changes in javascript variables, but changing element value with javascript does not generate any events.

If you create a dummy "input" event and trigger that on the element, it should cause the shadow DOM to detect the change and it will be saved appropriately.

you could simulate the event like this:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for replying to my post! I had no idea about shadow DOMs and I am excited to research on them as a new avenue to figuring out the solution to my issue. My preliminary attempts have not been successful, but I've only been trying for about half an hour since your post of course and I'll keep trying. Just in case you'd be inclined to answer an admittedly noob question, this code is on the right track, right? No worries if not; thank you so much for your input!

let huh = document.querySelector("#first_name")
huh.value = "Jane"
huh.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

Comment: I'd expect that to work if copy/paste works. When you paste something into an edit field, it sends an "input" event. You might also try a "change" event. That's most likely what they are watching